# Sinatra: /POST getting called multiple times

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra

I have a basic Sinatra app that uploads a file to S3 and then preforms some analysis on the file by downloading it from S3, converting to a hash and then putting it into a database.

Currently I have the script working: the file uploads, gets downloaded and analysed BUT, about halfway through the analysis the POST method gets called again and so the file gets redownloaded and starts getting analysed.

Script looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'aws'
require "./redo.rb"

get '/' do
  return %Q{
    <form action="upload" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload a file for processing:
      <div>
        <input type="file" name="file" value="" id="file">
      </div>
      <div>
        Email address: <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email">
      </div>
      <div>
        Subscribe? <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" checked="checked" id="sub">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload &uarr;">
      </div>
    </form>
  }
end

post '/upload' do

  customer_id = SecureRandom.uuid

  emailaddress = params[:email]
  subscribe    = params[:sub]
  file         = params[:file][:tempfile]
  filename     = params[:file][:filename]



       url = uploadtoS3(file, filename, customer_id)

      return url
    end
```

With a method in redo.rb that looks like this:

```
def uploadtoS3(attr_file, attr_filename, attr_customerID)
  puts "in uploadtoS3"
  bucket = $s3.buckets.create("#{attr_customerID}")
  obj = bucket.objects["#{attr_filename}"]
  obj.write(Pathname.new(attr_file.path))

#Call analysis methods here...

urlpointer = "https://#{bucket.name}.s3.amazonaws.com/#{attr_filename}"
return urlpointer
end
```

Why is the /POST method getting called multiple times?

Comment: Does your processing take a long time? I vaguely recall seeing browsers retry stuff after 60s or so

Comment: Good point by Frederick. You might consider using AJAX to do this, as that will simply wait patiently for the response.